# ranking in php sql

Tags: php, sql, rank

i have a table containing user, score and time.
i have to show rank according to score and if score is tie, time is the factor between tie socres.The user with less time should be on top.

```
query=SELECT user_id, total_marks, total_time, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM lang_totalset_marks ltm, (SELECT @curRank := 0) ra ORDER BY total_marks DESC .
```

its only ranking according to marks and i need to handel it according to time if score is tie.

Comment: add some example code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the question was so downvoted (but I see it was edited).  However, the solution is to just include the time column in the `order by`:

```
SELECT user_id, total_marks, total_time, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM lang_totalset_marks ltm CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @curRank := 0) params
ORDER BY total_marks DESC, total_time DESC;
```